# Monitor newly released code without real traffic

Tags: automation, test-automation, monitoring

As new code is released to production, without enough direct access to production execution environments I rely only on user traffic for monitoring. However not all use cases get covered via user traffic. In such scenario what is the recommended approach to perform thorough full-fledged monitoring (including an automated monitoring solution)?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Like [Hans-Martin Mosner said in his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/450708/4), you can only monitor what happens. If you have observability and monitoring in place, you'll know when users execute a scenario and get data about that execution. What are you trying to accomplish other than being able to see what users do and how the system performs when they do it?

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I have a lot of services deployed over AWS not all services get user traffic. In one of the recent deployments wrong code got deployed. Hence to check such scenarios I was wondering if people use an automated framework that runs some tests on prod and checks the flows.. I do not mean to ask for Health checks instead about verifying code flows. Wrong code deployment is a silly mistake that does not occur often. But I want to explore on the full-fledged code/flow monitoring after new releases

Comment: You're not looking for monitoring then, you're looking for testing-in-production. Automated testing in production is a thing people do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to have "health check" endpoints on your apps/services etc which you can constantly ping to check they are up and functional. Regardless of traffic.

Obviously with a low traffic service/feature, if you aren't seeing any errors it could be because its functioning correctly, or because its so broken no traffic is running through it.

A health check call allows you to check that the service is up and reachable, constant pinging of this check allows you to fire an alert as soon as it goes down, rather than waiting for user generated errors.

Re your comment

1. Full logging. Yes I would expect something like kibana or app insights on any system. This won't help if there is zero traffic though
2. Smoke Tests. I would expect some sort of tests be run on live after any deployment, even if its just you manually clicking though, ideally you have end to end tests from development that you can run against live as well to place a test order or whatever

Comment: my question is not about health checks instead on verifying code flows if they are working as expected after every release. Sort of an automated framework that runs on prod and provides result. Hope it clarifies. I am doing RCA on the incident I mentioned in the above comments. So I am trying to find a full-fledged monitoring for such scenarios.

Comment: Based on your comment in the question, this is the answer. You aren't trying to verify a "code flow". You're trying to understand what was deployed. If your health check endpoint returns a JSON message that contains the version of the service and perhaps the configuration settings (be sure to mask any sensitive data, like passwords or keys), you can monitor that the service is up and the correct version is deployed across your infrastructure. Very helpful in scaled environments with multiple servers or containers running the same service to see if the right version is available everywhere.

Comment: My health checks tend to do a bit more than just say "I'm alive" but less than an end to end "smoke test" which is the kind of think you would run after a deployment. I dont think a smoke test really falls under "monitoring" which implies you continually run them, which I would not advise, I think the downsides of the extra traffic and data generated aren't worth the extra sureity of the test over a healthcheck which maybe checks its internal connections and config, but assumes bug free code

Comment: Both the answer and comments help. The health check with the version info will work for me. Code is quality assured and assumed to be bug-free. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 2):

You can only monitor what's actually happening.

Cases which don't happen or happen rarely in production need to be tested before deployment, or if they are non-destructive but need production data may be tested after deployment. But you don't monitor them (except as part of your regular performance and error monitoring).

Comment: Do people use automated frameworks to run scheduled checks on live code to verify flow execution?

Comment: I don't think so. You perform integration tests which would cover this in an integration or UAT environment, and then you make sure that you deploy exactly that code into production. Running extensive modifying tests in production to just check whether someone made a deployment mistake sounds not very effective. This kind of requirement typically comes from IT management after something bad happened, but without enough understanding of the situation that lead to the problem. In the end, you have lots of checks for special cases which don't prevent the next (different) mistake.

Comment: Yeah true, It's the impact that causes such checks to be enforced.